# Python: Selenium webdriver Chrome opens up browser but not the site selected

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have just downloaded Anaconda (v 1.7.2) and spyder (Python 3.7.6).
I have chrome (Version 81.0.4044.92 64-bit)
Selenium version 3.141.0

When I write the code below I get the response that chrome opens up a new instance and a tab, but only the starting page, it never opens up the site I have pointed out.
I have tried to close all other chrome instances also but that didn't help.
I have added the following to the system environment variables 
C:\Users\aaa.bbb\Anaconda3\Scripts; 
c:\users\aaa.bbb\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\chromedriver;

---

```
from selenium import webdriver

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import pandas as pd

import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe")

driver.get('http://www.aftonbladet.se');

time.sleep(3)

driver.quit()
```

---

The response I get in spyder is:

```
runfile('C:/Users/aaa.bbb/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/aaa.bbb/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\aaa.bbb\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 8, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe")

  File "C:\Users\aaa.bbb\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()

  File "C:\Users\aaa.bbb\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()

  File "C:\Users\aaa.bbb\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 111, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)

WebDriverException: Service C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please download latest chrome driver which support to your browser version :
you can download  [Latest Chrome driver from here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads), Here r denotes relative path::

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r" path to your chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
baseUrl = "https://www.google.com"
driver.get(baseUrl)
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! It works now. I should have tried this forum earlier instead of googling for hours :)

Comment: I have done so, but since I am a new user they register it in the background and show it when I become a more experienced user (or something. That is how I read it at least)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a Chrome Webdriver instead of using the actual Chrome application. [Download Chrome Webdriver for Windows.](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

Edit this line to point to the Webdriver after download.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe")
```

Comment: Great! Thank you a lot! It works now. I should have tried this forum earlier instead of googling for hours :)